# Unable to get citrus TestContext object while to TestNg frame work to execute Citrus test cases

Tags: java, testng, citrus-framework

I am using TestNg frame work to execute citrus frame work test cases. In the below code I am unable to get citrus text context object getting an error while executing the test case

```
import org.testng.annotations.Optional;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.consol.citrus.annotations.CitrusResource;
import com.consol.citrus.annotations.CitrusXmlTest;
import com.consol.citrus.context.TestContext;
import com.consol.citrus.dsl.testng.TestNGCitrusTestRunner;
public class GenricTest extends TestNGCitrusTestRunner {
    static 
    {
      System.setProperty("citrus.spring.application.context", "file:G:\\Citrus\\citrus-context.xml");
    }
     @Test @Parameters("context")
    @CitrusXmlTest(packageScan = "file:C:\\xitrus")

    public void CitrusTest(@Optional @CitrusResource TestContext context) 
    {

    }
}
```

while executing above code to get citrus text context object i am getting the follwing error

```
[Utils] [ERROR] [Error] org.testng.TestNGException: 
Unsupported type parameter : class com.consol.citrus.context.TestContext
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.convertType(Parameters.java:318)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:203)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:443)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:569)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1308)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1036)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Comment: May I ask why do you need to access the TestContext? It is not really clear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to change the bean property values at run time so i need citrus text context object in the above code I referred text context object to xml executing test case method but I want context object in java dsl method while referring context object even to  citrus java dsl method i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you've configured in your Citrus context so I'll be posting a complete example.

Citrus tests are run with TestNG but Citrus itself is a Spring application. That means you can configure Beans inside a configuration class as you would in a Spring app and then you can use `@Autowired` to access the beans in your tests.

Here is an example configuration class where I've configured the beans that I need for testing:

```
@Import({})// you can import more configuration classes here
public class CitrusConfiguration {

    @Value("${inbound.service.url}")
    private String serviceUrl;
    @Value("${external.api.mock.port}")
    private int externalApiMockPort;

    @Bean
    public HttpClient inboundClient() {
        return CitrusEndpoints.http()
                .client()
                .requestUrl("http://" + serviceUrl)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpServer externalApiMock() {
        return CitrusEndpoints.http()
                .server()
                .port(externalApiMockPort)
                .autoStart(true)
                .timeout(10000)
                .build();
    }
}
```

After this we need to tell Citrus which class is the main configuration class inside a property file like this: `src/test/resources/citrus-application.properties`

```
citrus.spring.java.config=<your.package>.CitrusConfiguration
```

And now we can write a test like this:

```
@Test
public class InboundApiControllerIT extends TestNGCitrusTestRunner {

    @Autowired
    private HttpClient httpClient;

    @CitrusTest
    public void okTest() {

        http(action -> action.client(httpClient)
                .send()
                .post("/inbound")
                .payload("{" +
                        "\"userName\": \"Bruce.Wayne\"," +
                        "\"operation\": \"call-a-pizza\"" +
                        "}"));

        http(action -> action.client(httpClient)
                .receive()
                .response(HttpStatus.OK)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
                .payload("{" +
                        "\"success\": true" +
                        "}"));
    }
}
```

Please don't use a `static` block to configure Citrus (or anything in general) and use a setup like the one described above. If the [documentation](http://www.citrusframework.org/reference/html/index.html) cannot help you, you can always check the samples [here](https://github.com/christophd/citrus-samples).

The Citrus test components are pretty flexible inside the tests, so you should not need to change any of their configuration values dynamically. I also don't recommend doing this. If you need to change anything inside a test component (like an HttpClient) that cannot be explicitly configured inside a test action, then I recommend you create a new component with that special configuration.